# Identify number of Mappers & Reducers launched in a Pig script

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hortonworks-data-platform, tez

I'm using Hortonworks' sandbox VM to run `Hadoop` services. I executed a `Pig` filter script in `Tez` mode. Unlike `Hive`, the `Pig` log (console) doesn't show any information about the number of mappers & reducers being executed. Am I looking at a wrong place?

Answer (score 0):

When you are running in Tez mode, it doesn’t have mappers or reducers. Tez uses a DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph) of tasks to process the data. So the mappers/reducers are replaced by vertices and edges. If you are using Ambari, it provides a “Tez View” for more details about the job. Additionally, you may be able to enable/install the Tez UI (https://tez.apache.org/tez-ui.html) to see that information.